# XAML Creating GridView from Code Behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am practicing to learn XAML, but syntax is too verbose at my first impression. I am trying to  create a gridView from codebehind like below:

```
var gv = new GridView();

gv.Name = "itemGridView";
gv.ItemsSource = sampleDataGroups;
gv.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ItemGridView");
gv.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "Grouped Items");
gv.Padding = new Thickness(116, 137, 40, 46);
Grid.SetRowSpan(gv, 2);
```

While I can set my gridView' padding like a property, why I am using a static method of grid class to set its rowSpan ?

What is the reason behind that decision ?

**Note:** *I guess I can write an extension method to do that but I am curious why it is not made at the beginning.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is - a `GridView` (or pretty much every other control except the `Grid` itself) doesn't have a `RowSpan` property. Neither do these controls have the `Row`, `Column` and `ColumnSpan` properties.

Don't believe me? Check out [the MSDN documentation for `GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview). ;)

These are properties which you can use when you put something inside a `Grid`. Note that in XAML, you also set these properties up in a slightly different fashion: `Grid.Row="1"` as opposed to just `Padding="2"`.

You can also set up the `Grid` properties as you did with `AutomationProperties`. The `Grid.SetRowSpan` is just a shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Because setrow and setrowspan are attached properties which are available to gridview's parent GRID which decides the measuring and the layout of the children and hence are not directly available to the children (gridview).